# Bigquery - delay in data availability after BigQuery load job

Tags: google-bigquery

We see a 10-15 seconds in delay where the data is not immediately reflecting in BigQuery, when queried right after the Bigquery load job completes.
Is it expected to have this 10-15 seconds delay or should the data reflect immediately, when queried right after a Bigquery load job completes in a table?

Answer (score 0):

The data should be be available as soon as the load job completes. You can file a bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) with the load job id and the query job id for us to investigate further.